# Syntax to Overload the Post-Increment Operator ++ as a Nonmember Function

Tags: c++, overloading

I know this may be a silly question, but... is it really necessary to add the parameter name (int <parameter_name>), instead of just (int) in a definition of an operator function to overload "++" ( post-increment) ? or would it be optional?

example:

```
/* function prototype */
friend Cylinder operator++(Cylinder&, int);
```

---

```
/* function definition */
Cylinder operator++(Cylinder& n, int u)
{
    Cylinder temp = n;

    (n.radius)++;
    (n.height)++;

    return (temp);
}
```

and here it is the same except that it does not have the name of the parameter in the definition function (I only ask, because I am curious, that even though it does not have it, the program still works, and also if it would be good practice to put it or not?):

Example:

```
/* function prototype */
friend Cylinder operator++(Cylinder&, int);
```

---

```
/* function definition */
Cylinder operator++(Cylinder& n, int)
{
    Cylinder temp = n;

    (n.radius)++;
    (n.height)++;

    return (temp);
}
```

Full program:
**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

#include "Cylinder.h"

using namespace std;


int
main(void)
{
    Cylinder Cylinder1(5.0, 10.0); //radius = 5.0 and height = 10.0
    Cylinder Cylinder2(3.5, 20.0); //radius = 3.5 and height 20.0
    Cylinder Cylinder3;
    Cylinder Cylinder4;
    Cylinder Cylinder5;
    
    cout << "Cylinder1 --- " << Cylinder1 << endl;
    cout << "Cylinder2 --- " << Cylinder2 << endl;


    Cylinder3 = Cylinder1 + Cylinder2;
    cout << "Cylinder1 + Cylinder2 = " << "Cylinder3 --- " << Cylinder3 << endl;

    Cylinder4 = Cylinder1 - Cylinder2;
    cout << "Cylinder1 - Cylinder2 = " << "Cylinder4 --- " << Cylinder4 << endl;

    Cylinder5 = Cylinder1 * Cylinder2;
    cout << "Cylinder1 * Cylinder2 = " << "Cylinder5 --- " << Cylinder5 << endl;

    cout << "Compare Cylinder1 > Cylinder2 --- " << endl;
    if (Cylinder1 > Cylinder2)
        cout << "Cylinder1 is greater than Cylinder2." << endl;
    else
        cout << "Cylinder1 is less than or equal to Cylinder2." << endl << endl;
    
    Cylinder1++;
    cout << "Cylinder1++ --- " << endl;
    cout << "New dimension of Cylinder1: " << Cylinder1 << endl;

    Cylinder4 = Cylinder3++;
    cout << "Cylinder4 = Cylinder3++ --- " << endl;
    cout << "New dimension of Cylinder3: " << Cylinder3 << endl;
    cout << "New dimension of Cylinder4: " << Cylinder4 << endl;

    cout << "Cylinder4 != Cylinder3 --- Cylinder4 is " 
         << (Cylinder4 != Cylinder3 ? "not equal to Cylinder3 " : "equal to Cylinder3") << endl;
    cout << "Cylinder4 >= Cylinder3 --- Cylinder4 is " 
         << (Cylinder4 >= Cylinder3 ? "greater or equal to Cylinder3 " : "less than Cylinder3 ") << endl;
    cout << "Cylinder4 == Cylinder3 --- Cylinder4 is " 
         << (Cylinder4 == Cylinder3 ? "equal to Cylinder3 " : "not equal to Cylinder3") << endl;
    cout << "Cylinder4 < Cylinder3 --- Cylinder4 is " 
         << (Cylinder4 < Cylinder3 ? "less than Cylinder3 " : "greater than or equal to Cylinder3") << endl;
    cout << "Cylinder4 <= Cylinder3 --- Cylinder4 is " 
         << (Cylinder4 <= Cylinder3 ? "less than or equal to Cylinder3 " : "greater than Cylinder3") << endl;
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

**Cylinder.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

#include "Cylinder.h"


Cylinder::Cylinder(void)
{
    this->radius = 1;
    this->height = 1;
}


Cylinder::Cylinder(double _radius, double _height)
{
    this->radius = _radius;
    this->height = _height;
}


const Cylinder&
Cylinder::operator=(const Cylinder &n)
{   
    this->radius = n.radius;
    this->height = n.height;

    return (*this);
}

Cylinder
Cylinder::operator+(const Cylinder& n) const
{
    Cylinder new_n;

    new_n.radius = radius + n.radius;
    new_n.height = height + n.height;
    
    return (new_n);
}


Cylinder
Cylinder::operator-(const Cylinder& n) const
{
    Cylinder new_n;

    new_n.radius = radius - n.radius;
    new_n.height = height - n.height;

    return (new_n);
}


Cylinder
Cylinder::operator*(const Cylinder& n) const
{
    Cylinder new_n;

    new_n.radius = radius * n.radius;
    new_n.height = height * n.height;

    return (new_n);
}


bool
Cylinder::operator==(const Cylinder& n) const
{
    Cylinder new_n;

    return ((new_n.radius == n.radius && 
         new_n.height == n.height)  ? true : false);
}


bool
Cylinder::operator!=(const Cylinder& n) const
{
    Cylinder new_n;

    return ((new_n.radius != n.radius && 
         new_n.height != n.height)  ? true : false);
}


bool
Cylinder::operator>=(const Cylinder& n) const
{
    Cylinder new_n;

    return ((new_n.radius >= n.radius && 
         new_n.height >= n.height)  ? true : false);
}


bool
Cylinder::operator>(const Cylinder& n) const
{
    Cylinder new_n;

    return ((new_n.radius > n.radius &&
         new_n.height > n.height)  ? true : false);
}


bool
Cylinder::operator<(const Cylinder& n) const
{
    Cylinder new_n;

    return ((new_n.radius < n.radius &&
         new_n.height < n.height)  ? true : false);
}


bool
Cylinder::operator<=(const Cylinder& n) const
{
    Cylinder new_n;

    return ((new_n.radius <= n.radius &&
         new_n.height <= n.height)  ? true : false);
}


Cylinder
operator++(Cylinder& n, int)
{
    Cylinder temp = n;

    (n.radius)++;
    (n.height)++;

    return (temp);
}

ostream &operator<<(ostream& out, const Cylinder& n)
{
    out << "Radius: " << n.radius << '\t'
        << "Height: " << n.height << std::endl; 
    return (out);
}
```

**Cylinder.h**

```
#ifndef CYLINDER_H_INCLUDED
#define CYLINDER_H_INCLUDED

using namespace std;


class Cylinder {

    public:
        /* function members */
        Cylinder(void);
        Cylinder(double, double);
        
        const Cylinder& operator=(const Cylinder &);

        Cylinder operator+(const Cylinder&) const;
        Cylinder operator-(const Cylinder&) const;
        Cylinder operator*(const Cylinder&) const;

        bool operator==(const Cylinder&) const;
        bool operator!=(const Cylinder&) const;
        bool operator>=(const Cylinder&) const;
        bool operator>(const Cylinder&) const;
        bool operator<(const Cylinder&) const;
        bool operator<=(const Cylinder&) const;

        friend Cylinder operator++(Cylinder&, int);
        friend ostream &operator<<(ostream& out, const Cylinder&);
        
    private:
        /* data members */
        double radius;
        double height;
};

#endif  /* CYLINDER_H_INCLUDED */
```

Comment: You add a cilinder to a cilinder of the same size and you get both double the height **and** the radius? What kind of cilinder is that? Your code is in violation of the principle  of least surprise there... I'd also expect a cilinder to grow at the same speed *relative* to the current size, not just by a specific unit in both directions.

Comment: Well, I just tried to write the code as they told me in the instructions, I also think that there are things that don't make sense. But, since I have to follow the instructions provided by the instructor, I have no choice.

Comment: I thought that if he wanted us to practice certain things, he could have provided something else...

Comment: Well, to test the class / method / op overloading design the model doesn't have to make sense I suppose, but I would also argue that it would be easy to create a good model or a different example. Creating a design that would be shot down by anybody with good sense, well, I don't know. Maybe you could make yourself popular by recommending a better model.

Comment: You're right, since I still have time I'll try to see if I can do something much better. By the way, do you have any books you can recommend, as you can see I'm new to programming. I'd be really grateful.

Comment: Not sure about that. I just read "Clean code" but I think it's a bit of a hodge-podge (it's by different authors) and it does seem to simplify things to a fault (e.g. always use exceptions instead of returning errors, that should be expanded by the idea that normal running code should avoid exceptions by testing IO without throwing). You can learn a lot about models of abstraction by reading "Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software", it's famous, maybe a bit advanced now. My fave book is "Effective Java" but there will be a lot in there not directly applicable to C++.

Comment: I'm sure they are very interesting books, but thanks anyway, I'll try if I look for one that can help me. To learn at least from the basics. And I'll take a look at the ones you mention, maybe they can help me in some way in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Answer to your question

> is it really necessary to add the parameter name (int <parameter_name>), instead of just (int) in a definition of an operator function to overload "++" ( post-increment) ? or would it be optional?

That is not necessary. If a function parameter is not used in the body of a function, you do not need to give that parameter a name.

## Cylinder arithmetic doesn't make sense

What does it mean to add two cylinders together? Or to multiply them? You are implementing overloads for the arithmetic and relational operators, and just blindly apply those operators to the `radius` and `height`, but that doesn't make any sense.

Consider your cylinders are all made out of the same homogeneous material. If you add two identical cylinders together, what do you expect the result to be? Another cylinder that has double the volume? But if you add the radii and height individually, then the volume will actually increase eightfold. The same goes for mass. What if you add a cylinder with a very small radius but large height to one with a large radius but small height? If you subtract cylinders, what does it mean if the result has a negative value for both radius and height?

Your relational operators also don't make sense, at least they don't form a [total order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order). Consider comparing two cylinders A with radius 1 and height 2, and cylinder B with radius 2 and height 1. Then `operator<`, `operator>` and `operator==` will all return `false`. Also consider that you can have two cylinders with equal radius but different height. Then both `operator==` and `operator!=` return `false`.

Actually, the operators don't even do that. Why are most of them creating a new `Cylinder` object and using that instead of `this`?

## Use `'\n'` instead of `std::endl`

Prefer using [`'\n'` instead of `std::endl`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/stdendl-vs-n); the latter is equivalent to the former but also forces the output to be flushed, which is usually not necessary and can have a negative impact on performance.

## Unnecessary code

Your code has some unnecessary parentheses and ternary operators. Consider:

```
return ((new_n.radius < n.radius &&
         new_n.height < n.height)  ? true : false);
```

First, the outer parentheses are not necessary at all. Second, the ternary operator doesn't do anything. Everything before the `?` is already a boolean value, so you can just write:

```
return new_n.radius < n.radius && new_n.height < n.height;
```

## `operator=` should return a non-`const` reference

`operator=` only makes sense on a non-`const` object, and the return value should also be a non-`const` reference.

## Use `()` for functions that take no parameters

`(void)` is only necessary in C, in C++ you can just write:

```
Cylinder();
```

## Prefer initializer lists to initialize member variables

While your constructors are valid, prefer using initializer lists to initialize member variables, like so:

```
Cylinder::Cylinder(): radius(1), height(1) {}
Cylinder::Cylinder(double radius_, double height_): radius(radius_), height(height_) {}
```

Or combine them using default parameter values:

```
Cylinder::Cylinder(double radius_ = 1, double height_ = 1): radius(radius_), height(height_) {}
```